# Get Index From String in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array like so:
    `String[] articles = {"a", "and", "the"};`
And I want to know how to get the array index from a certain term. Is there a method along the lines of `articles.getIndex("the");` and it will return an int (in this case, 2)?

Answer (score 3):

You can create List wrapping your array and use its `indexOf` method

```
Arrays.asList(yourArray).indexOf(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write method for that

```
public int indexByValue(String data, String[] array) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      if (array[i].equals(data)) index = i;

    return index;
}
```